# Using a variable set in one method in another

Tags: c#

So I am just getting into using C# as I have to use it next year for school. I am making a simple command line program that does the following.

- Gets the date and time
- Displays a menu asking what the user would like to add onto the date/time (E.g Months, Days, Minutes
- Get user input (1,2,3 etc)
- Display a menu asking how they would like the result to be formatted (Short Date, Long Date, Short Time, Long Time)
- Output the final result

I have set each part into a separate method. So the first menu has its own method, Then the second menu has its own menu which is called when the first menu is done with addition.

However I want to be able to use the result that is stored in the variable in the original method in the second method (The output menu one). Is this possible to do? Or do I have to approach the situation differently?

In the following code I am not going to include the menu bit as its not important. The if statements are just saying which option the user has selected, they are all the same just do slightly different tasks.

This is the part that takes user input of what they would like to add. It then puts the result in dateResult.

```
else if (result == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many days do you want to add?: ");
            int dayResult = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            DateTime dateResult = dateValue.AddDays(dayResult);
            Console.ReadLine();
            return true;
            OutputMenu(); // Starts the next menu for the output

        }
```

Output part

```
        if(result == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dateResult.ToShortTimeString()); // HH:MM
            return true; 
        }
```

Doing this says that dateResult does not exist in the current context. Now I know that it is out of the scope but is there a way I can make that variable be able to be used in other methods?

Note: This is my first actual program in C# so I don't expect everything to be super well done. But please do give advice on how to better it.

Comment: Do a Google search for variable scope, that should help. Nvm, closing as dupe instead.

Comment: declare the variable outside the curly braces.  Definitions are valid only within their enclosing brace in most C-based languages.